# ERROR calling out CURDATE()

Tags: sql, oracle

Why is there an error when i called out the CURDATE?

```
UPDATE TABLENAME
    SET DATEATR= (TO_DATE(CURDATE() ,'DD-MM-YYYY') - WORKDATE /365 );
```

Comment: Can you post, what error is getting thrown?

Comment: ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00904: "CURDATE": invalid identifier

Comment: ORS-00904 error means, there is some problem with column name. Please check it, if you are providing valid column name.

Comment: i've no issue callin out sysdate instead..

Answer (score 6):

> ERROR at line 2: ORA-00904: "CURDATE": invalid identifier

you are using `ORACLE` and not `MySQL` right? the equivalent of `CURDATE()` in `Oracle` are

- **[CURRENT_DATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions044.htm#SQLRF00628)**
- **[SYSDATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions191.htm#SQLRF06124)**